# Merge hourly prices history to daily

Tags: sql, postgresql

Database looks like:

```
ID | volume | timestamp (timestamp without time zone)
 1 | 300    | 2015-05-27 00:
 1 | 250    | 2015-05-28 00:
 2 | 13     | 2015-05-25 00:
 1 | 500    | 2015-06-28 22:
 1 | 100    | 2015-06-28 23:
 2 | 11     | 2015-06-28 21:
 2 | 15     | 2015-06-28 23:
```

Is there any way to merge hourly prices history, that oldest than 1 month, to daily and put them back to table? That means merge hourly records into 1 record, with sum volume and timestamp of 00 hour (I mean only day, 2013-08-15 00:00:00).

So, wanted result:

```
ID | volume | timestamp
 1 | 300    | 2015-05-27 00:
 1 | 250    | 2015-05-28 00:
 2 | 13     | 2015-05-25 00:
 1 | 600    | 2015-06-28 00:
 2 | 26     | 2015-06-28 00:
```

Comment: It is unclear what your are asking about. Please describe the problem you have more explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, not quite for me. Merge = add? Which to what? Please understand that most people here do not have hourly prices, even less wanting to merge them to history.

Comment: Could you provide the desired output ? Is the timestamp really `28.07.2015 22:` or is it something like `28.07.2015 22:00:00` ?

Comment: @Pholochtairze, yes, it's hour without minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help @Pholochtairze and @a_horse_with_no_name.
Final query:

```
WITH merged_history AS (
    SELECT item_id, SUM(history_volume) AS history_volume,
        (SUM(history_medianprice * history_volume) / SUM(history_volume)) AS history_medianprice,
        history_timestamp::date
    FROM prices_history
    WHERE history_timestamp < NOW()::date - INTERVAL '1 month'
    GROUP BY item_id, history_timestamp::date),
upsert AS ( 
    UPDATE prices_history AS h
    SET history_volume = mh.history_volume, history_medianprice = mh.history_medianprice
    FROM merged_history AS mh
    WHERE h.item_id = mh.item_id AND h.history_timestamp = mh.history_timestamp RETURNING h.*)
INSERT INTO prices_history
SELECT item_id, history_volume, history_medianprice, history_timestamp
FROM merged_history
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM upsert AS u, merged_history AS mh
    WHERE u.item_id = mh.item_id AND u.history_timestamp = mh.history_timestamp);

DELETE FROM prices_history
WHERE history_timestamp != history_timestamp::date
    AND history_timestamp < NOW()::date - INTERVAL '1 month';
```

(It's took 2 minutes to complete this chalenge (3m rows) :D I will run it once a week. It will be a bit modified later, coz no need to merge already merged data)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a simply group by based on the date without the time:

```
select id,
       sum(volume) as volume, 
       timestamp::date as timestamp
from the_table
group by id, timestamp::date
order by id, timestamp::date;
```

`timestamp::date` will cast the column named `timestamp`(which btw is a *horrible* name for a column) to a `date` thus removing the time part of the timestamp (the data type).

`timestamp::date` is Postgres specific. The ANSI SQL equivalent is `cast(timestamp as date)` (did I mention that *timestamp* is a horrible name for a column?)

Comment: Unnamed Horse, I tryed to make my question clear. I wanted to make this changes in table, not select.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I posted my final query as answer if you want to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to modify the table with this new data, I thought of a select into. Here is how I proceeded (see [sql fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3824a/6/4)) :

1. Select the data you want and insert it in a temporary table (foo_temp)
2. Empty your first table (foo)
3. Copy the data from the temporary table into the (now) empty table (from foo_temp to foo)
4. Drop the temporary table

Here is the code :

```
/*Step 1 : Select the data you need and insert it in a temporary table*/
SELECT 
    ID,
    SUM(volume) as volume, 
    timestamp_field::date
INTO foo_temp
FROM foo
GROUP BY 
    ID,
    timestamp_field::date
ORDER BY 
    ID,
    timestamp_field::date;

/*Step 2 : Delete data from the table*/
DELETE FROM foo;

/*Step3 : Take data from the temporary table and insert it into the "main" table*/
INSERT INTO foo(ID,volume,timestamp_field)
SELECT * FROM foo_temp;

/*Step 4: Drop the temporary table*/
DROP TABLE foo_temp;

/*Step 5 : Yeah it works !*/
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

> I must admit @a_horse_with_no_name did most of the job and his answer was elegant.

Note : There is probably a better way of doing the job.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I posted my final query as answer if you want to see it.